# Install ubuntu Linux directly onto hard drive via a bridge

Tags: installation, usb, drive

the windows XP 32-bit on my laptop recently died and I want to install linux now.
The problem is the laptop has no cd or floppy drive anymore and is not able to boot from USB.
I borrowed a "bridge" from a friend, which allows me to connect the hard drive to the USB-port of my other laptop(win 7 64bit) which then recognizes it as a hard drive.

How can I get a bootable OS on this hard drive?
I have tried installing it the usual way and just select the other hard drive, but my other laptop won't open the 32bit installer. But I need a 32bit OS for my old laptop

Comment: Do you want a clean install of it or just want to install inside window

Comment: What do you mean "won't open the 32 bit installer"?

Comment: What does `the windows XP 32-bit on my laptop recently died` actually mean?

Answer (score 1):

I would let the second computer make a lan with mine and then just follow the network installation of ubuntu. Read the full guide [here.](http://www.packtpub.com/article/network-based-ubuntu-installations)

Answer (score 0):

To [install 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04) on a temporarily plugged in harddrive you need to **boot** the other laptop with the installation medium (CD/USB). The Windows installer program installs Ubuntu via Wubi and is **not suitable for this**.

For safety reasons, may I recommend you unplug your harddrive from the healthy laptop before you start installing Ubuntu on the "external" drive? If that is not an option please take extra care to not erroneously install Ubuntu to the healthy laptop.